# Question about making footnotes for material taken from a class handout that has original sources

Tags: writing

This is my first time writing a paper that requires footnotes, and in the instructions the professor has stated he wants the exact reference when we use materials from one of his class handouts. An example of information I want to take from a class handout would be:
Justinian, Digest 2.13.12: [Callistratus]: Women seem to be removed from
the job of a banker, since that is man’s work. (Where Justinian's Digest would be the original source) What is the correct way to reference this information in a footnote?

Comment: I think you need to include more information in your question. When you say "Justinian, Digest", what *exactly* are you referring to: what edition, published where, by whom, and in translation or not. ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_(Roman_law) )

Comment: Unless you improve your question by adding the kind of material I have suggested, it will not be possible for anyone to answer it, and your question will be closed.